# How can I extract or parse data from post contents' shortcodes into an array?

Tags: shortcode, post-content, parse

I'm migrating from one Visual Page editor to another. I'm extracting the texts surrounded by the shortcode opening and closing tags.

Before I write my own parsing script, I wanted to make sure that Wordpress didn't already have a solution for this, or something else didn't already exist either. I feel like this is a common need that there may already be something to handle it.

Here is an example of the post_content data. As you can see this can get infinitely nested and complex.

I want to pull the data out and put it into an array. So that it's a lot easier to read, I highlighted the only two text phrases in the data.

> `[cs_content][cs_section parallax="false" separator_top_type="none" separator_top_height="50px" separator_top_angle_point="50" separator_bottom_type="none" separator_bottom_height="50px" separator_bottom_angle_point="50" style="margin: 0px;padding: 45px 0px;"][cs_row inner_container="true" marginless_columns="false" style="margin: 0px auto;padding: 0px;"][cs_column fade="false" fade_animation="in" fade_animation_offset="45px" fade_duration="750" type="1/1" style="padding: 0px;"][cs_text]**this is text**[/cs_text][/cs_column][/cs_row][/cs_section][cs_section parallax="false" separator_top_type="none" separator_top_height="50px" separator_top_angle_point="50" separator_bottom_type="none" separator_bottom_height="50px" separator_bottom_angle_point="50" style="margin: 0px;padding: 45px 0px;"][cs_row inner_container="true" marginless_columns="false" style="margin: 0px auto;padding: 0px;"][cs_column fade="false" fade_animation="in" fade_animation_offset="45px" fade_duration="750" type="1/1" style="padding: 0px;"][cs_text]**text phrase 2**[/cs_text][/cs_column][/cs_row][/cs_section][/cs_content]`

Once it's extracted, I want to store it in an array like such:

```
$data = array(
    'this is text', 
    'text phrase 2'
);
```

I can handle that though. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel. Note, I don't care about any of the data within the shortcode definitions themselves.

Comment: Is the text you're after, always wrapped in `[cs_text]...[/cs_text]` ?

Comment: Ah, glad you caught that. No, it won't always exactly be [cs_text]...[/cs_text]. But it will always be [cs_*]...[/cs_*]. 'text' just means text element. There are 100s of elements cs_image, cs_slider, etc

Answer (score 0):

Not really a WordPress question, but you can use the PHP function `preg_match_all` to extract all the text wrapped in `[cs_text]` tags like so:

```
function wpse_265295_extract_cs_text( $subject ) {
  $pattern = "#\[cs_text\](.*?)\[/cs_text\]#s";
  preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches );
  return isset( $matches[1] ) ? $matches[1] : [];
}
```

If you're looking to extract arbitrary shortcodes:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'extract_shortcodes' ) ) :
function extract_shortcodes( $subject, $shortcode ) {
  $pattern = "#\[$shortcode\](.*?)\[/$shortcode\]#s";
  preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches );
  return isset( $matches[1] ) ? $matches[1] : [];
}
endif;
```

Comment: [`get_shortcode_regex()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) is possibly useful here.